# Move number closer to a certain number, by algorithm, not thinking.

Tags: algorithms

So, I am working on a project, and need a way to move a number closer to a certain value. It is not as simple as "you just add/subtract it". I **don't want any "ifs"**.

I want an algorithm for moving a closer to b, by c. If a was 10, b was 5, and c was 2, the algorithm would return 8. If all was the same, but b was 13, it would return 12. **I know what addition/subtraction is**. I need a way to do this without any **ifs**, so I could not look at 10, and see it was less than 13, "so addition". I do have a way of clamping a, so it could not go over it, if b was greater than a, and under it if a was less than b.

I just need a way of doing this in the eyes of a computer, and this computer does not have any "ifs", but it can just do math. I'm **fine with things like absolute value** and things that would require some if, but it has to be something well known to math.

Sorry if this is a simple question, I just can't see it.

Comment: Keep it as $\frac{c}{|b-a|}(b-a)+a$, such that it works for arbitrary points in a vector space and not only real numbers.

Comment: What do you want your algorithm to return if $a=10, b=11, c=3$?

Comment: Just to say, computers are very comfortable with conditional operations, as is math generally.  There's nothing non-mathematical (nor complex) about an if/then operation.

Comment: Why are you avoiding ifs? That seems like a very strange requirement.

Comment: Computers also do [branch prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) and [speculative execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution) and there is a time expended when there is branch misprediction. So, it is reasonable to try to avoid IFs in critical parts of the code and whenever possible.

Comment: @plop: I would avoid giving advice good programming practice on MSE. Headlines like "Mathematician advises avoiding user of IF whenever possible" aren't good news. I know that isn't what you wrote, but it is a very easy misreading of what you wrote. Personally, I always advise programmers to write the clearest and simplest way of expressing their intentions in code and to consider source code optimisations only when performance analysis shows it may be needed.

Comment: They already judged, for whatever reason that is not our concern (even more for this being MSE), that they want to avoid IFs. What I would avoid is all the questioning of that choice, as if it were something strange to want to do. It is something perfectly reasonable to want to do in some cases. That is their question, let solutions be given. There is no basis for judging them and even less for something false like saying that there is nothing complex about and if/then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\sgn}{\mathrm{sgn}}$Looks like you want $a+c$ if $b > a$ and $a-c$ if $b<a$. So you want $a +\sgn (b-a)c$, where $\sgn(b-a)$ refers to the sign of $b-a$. Now, recall that $\color{blue}{\sgn (b-a) = \frac{b-a}{|b-a|}}$. So you can try using the formula $\boxed{a'=a + \frac{b-a}{|b-a|}c}$.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I think about it, the only thing I was missing was the way to get the sign. (: